# What webhook should I use for an audio alert in azure for when a website goes down?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webhooks

So I have been looking and I cannot find anything helpful towards what I should use.

All I want to know is what webhook will allow me to have an audio alert when one of our websites goes down. We use azure to host all the sites.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of an Audio alert are you looking for exactly? An alert can trigger a Voice call as of today. Also, how're you configuring the alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure doesn't provide such native feature. And I don't think you can do it via some webhook. Webhook is kinda another website hosted somewhere. It has no permission or power to play any audio on any client computers without users access it on their computers.

The only option I can think of is to send email out when web app is stopped. In Azure, select "Stop Web App (sites)" alert as condition, then the people concerned create a rule on their computers like this if you use Outlook:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web monitoring tool like [distill.io](https://distill.io) on your website. 
It will send you an email alert when anything changes on your website. It gives you an additional feature to set conditions on the alerts - so it only sends you alerts when website is down ( to avoid spamming)